# How to make button slide with animated collapsible div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which collapses on a button click. Code as follows:

```js
const collapse = () => {
  const title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.classList.add('d-none');
  const out = document.getElementById('out');
  out.classList.add('collapse');
}
```

```css
.out {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.collapse {
  width: 65px;
}

.btn {
  width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div id='out' class='out'>
  <span id='title'>Title</span>
  <button class='btn' onclick='collapse()'>Collapse</button>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a transition effect, so that the div would collapse smoothly, the button would move smoothly to the left end with div collapse. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** I may have misunderstood what your intended outcome is. If you comment on here what you'd like it to do, I can make it more correctly align. :)

I've added an example with what you have, but I'd recommend just adding and removing a class based on the state.

Basically, you just toggle the 'collapse' classname, and add `transition` properties to the div class, as well as the collapse class. You can see the code below:

```js
const collapse = () => {
  const out = document.getElementById('out');
  // We only have to toggle the collapse class
  out.classList.toggle('collapse');
}
```

```css
.out {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  /* This transition happens when the collapse is removed */
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.d-none {
  height: 0;
}

.collapse {
  width: 0;
  /* This transition happens when the collapse class is added */
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='out' class='out'>
  <span id='title'>Title</span>
</div>
<button class='btn' onclick='collapse()'>Collapse</button>
```